# I want to load only the body of the (Live)source url in in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am doing the task of the load only body tag of the source URL in Iframe.No other than it.
 I have done following code for it.
one javascript function

```
Function test(){
var iframe=document.getElementById('test');
iframe.contentWindow.document.body.style.backgroundColor="green";
}

<iframe id="Iframe1" width="700" height="400" src="http://www.facebook.com" Onload=test()></iframe>
```

But no effect.

My actual task is to apply my custom css to that body tag only.

Please suggest any solution.

Comment: The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) won't let you do this.

Comment: ok. thanks for you reply , but is there any other way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work unless you explicitly switch off cross-domain scripting protection in your browser settings. You may try your luck with writing [Greasemonkey Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/sl/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).